# Is it possible to remove "secure erase" menu item from motherboard UEFI firmware?

Tags: uefi, msi

How expensive will it be if it is not free? Also, I would like to hide symbols display while entering password. Is it possible?
Motherboard manufacturer is MSI.
Year is 2023 or 2022.

Comment: What menu item? What password? Where are you seeing this?

Comment: why wouldn't it not be possible? ... `is it possible?` questions are somewhat useless because the answer is almost always a `yes`

Comment: To follow @jsotola's answer: ...with nation-state resources, the range of possible is quite broad.

Answer (score 2):

Very expensive in relation to time costs.

Is it possible? For sure, but as already mentioned, the time costs are tremendous.

You'd have to patch the firmware. And nowadays motherboard manufacturers like MSI use signing mechanisms to check the validity of the firmware.

You have to become a *firmware modder* to achieve this.

Then you can probably bypass the signature check and other security measures by accessing (hopefully present) debugging interfaces (in hardware).

I'm really no expert in that regard, but what you are trying to do involves *a lot of work*. And, frankly, if you have to ask how to do it, you'll probably face a steep learning curve that you'll only master if you're really tenacious.

Maybe you'll find a fast-food solution on the internet, but that surely comes with some security tradeoffs.